# How to properly use variadic args in Golang?

Tags: go

I am complete beginner with Go and I am trying to pass variadic args to `encodeit` method as a string that will hash the string, otherwise pass an empty string. I wan't to print out hashed string.

I have tried multiple things, but could not get it to work.

```
package main

import(
    "crypto/sha512"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func encodeit(content string) string {
    sha_512 := sha512.New()
    sha_512.Write([]byte(content))
    contentH := sha_512.Sum(nil)
    contentHash := hex.EncodeToString([]byte(contentH))
    return contentHash
}

func some(payload ...string) {
    if len(payload) == 1 {
        contentHash := encodeit(payload)
    } else {
        contentHash := encodeit("")
    }
    return contentHash
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(some(`{"stockSymbol": "TSLA"}`))
}
```

Here is the error log

```
# command-line-arguments
.\stackOverflow.go:19:26: cannot use payload (type []string) as type string in argument to encodeit
.\stackOverflow.go:23:2: too many arguments to return
.\stackOverflow.go:23:9: undefined: contentHash
.\stackOverflow.go:27:18: some("{\"stockSymbol\": \"TSLA\"}") used as value
```

Comment: You have 4 completely unrelated compiler errors here. Start with one thing at a time. I would suggest walking through the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) to start.

Answer (score 1):

`payload` becomes an array of strings ([]string) when using an ellipsis (...). It can be iterated on using a key,value for loop:

```
func printEncoded(payload ...string) {
    for i, value := range payload {
        fmt.Println(i, encode(value))
    }
}
```

Use `printEncoded("TSLA","AMD","DOW")` and you won't have to create your own `[]string` array as an argument (`[]string{"TSLA","AMD","DOW"}`).

You're also going to want to take a look at the [JSON](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package for parsing: `{"stockSymbol": "TSLA"}`

[Fixed Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zeglPXps2qw)

Answer (score 0):

check your func return value:

```
func some(payload ...string) string
```

you missed the return type `string`.